# Background Image is not visible Css

Tags: html, css

I added a background image and it is not visible in the page.

This is what i tried:

Css:

```
div{


    background: url(http://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/CN103289961A/CN103289961AD00172.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: contain;
        -moz-background-size: contain;
        -o-background-size: contain;
        background-size: contain;
        vertical-align: middle;
        background-position: center;
    }
```

[Demo Link](https://jsfiddle.net/8sjjxp0e/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the div does not have measures width and height fixed or defined.

```
background: url(http://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/CN103289961A/CN103289961AD00172.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-position: center;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Working [link](https://jsfiddle.net/8sjjxp0e/1/)

Comment: Thank you, it works fine, but I have a image with text, its getting blurred. https://jsfiddle.net/8sjjxp0e/4/

Comment: well this behaviour is because when you uses the contain property of background-size it tries to fit into this measures then the image becomes blurred.

Comment: No, there are many ways to prevent this, like use svg images, responsive images instead of background, multiple images for multiple sizes, etc, the possibilities are a lot, you must choose any that fits into your needs.